# How to push intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to "push" the intent `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in a service in `onStart`

I tried this:

```
Intent batteryChanged = new Intent();
batteryChanged.setAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
startActivity(batteryChanged);
```

How can I update the widget when it starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send that `Intent` yourself (see the excerpt below from the docs explaining it is a system intent). If your app needs to know when the battery state has changed you should be using a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for when the system updates it.

> public static final String ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
>
> ...
>
> **This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.**
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"

Comment: Hmm I need to set battery level when someone add widget. When widget is already added it's waiting for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and works good, but as I said on the beginning I need to set battery level when I add widget. :)

Comment: @Evelan: Call `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))`. Since `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky broadcast, this will return the last-broadcast `Intent` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, which will contain the extras you need.

Comment: Ok. I've just second question. What happening when i call the startService twice? It's solving my problem, but I would rather to ask here before I upload app to Android Market with this :)

Comment: If you use the approach as explained by CommonsWare above, then you aren't actually registering a `BroadcastReceiver` but instead you simply get the last broadcast 'sticky'. This can be done any number of times without problem.